# Genre of this Sample Library

Tags: theory, composition, samples, genre

I'm music Producer and trying to achieve this type of "samples" Music.

- What Genre are these "samples"?
- Can you recommend me some music that sounds like that?
- What instrument do i need use for this type of Music?

Thank you

Comment: Wow, a real paint by numbers sample pack! They’re just 70’s and 80’s subtractive synths, you get a pretty good emulation in most daw’s. I recommend getting into making your own. As for genre, genre is a vague thing, but the title should point you in the right direction..

Comment: Even though off-topic, this is an unfortunately naïve question. We didn't have 4,372 'genres' to describe things back then. Start your reseach, as hinted in the video title, with music from 1985 …though to tighten that search, try 'American music from 1985' as what I listened to owes nothing to the European pioneers of this type of sound. Even the sounds in the video are quite naïve themselves. There's nothing adventurous in there, just some guy pressing presets on synths of the age.

Comment: sorry i'm new to this platform what should the question be to not be off topic. I really loved the type of this music but didnt find album or didnt know what should i search to find something sounds like this

Comment: @OwenM Thank you for your Comment, it helped me. Can you recommend me some albums or artists that sound like this ?

Comment: @justaguys well, it's a bit of generic homage to all synth 80's stuff, as sample packs tend to be! The modern day pastiche is called synth wave, more or less. If you look for 80's movie sountracks you'll find some of the more dramatic stuff. Think big, pop culture movies, rather than indie films. But there will be elements they've copied from in lots of 70's and 80's synth pop. It won't sound identical, as this sample pack is more of a 'collection of vibes' amped up for the 21st century. It's broadly more American than European, maybe start with the Bladerunner soundtrack?